# SQL. Wrong result of COUNT() function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, count

I can't find problem. I have many tables joined each other. I need to get count of form instances from `FormInstances` table (should count `Id` column), but It returing wrong data.

So my query looks like:

```
DECLARE @dateStart  DATE        = NULL,
@dateEnd        DATE            = NULL,
@workshop       NVARCHAR(60)    = '',
@shiftNr        NVARCHAR(60)    = '',
@article        NVARCHAR(60)    = '',
@controllier    NVARCHAR(60)    = 'Name of Controlier'

SELECT COUNT(FI.Id) AS [Count of Instances]
FROM FormInstances AS FI
LEFT JOIN FormFields        AS FF
    ON FI.FormVersionId = FF.FormVersionid 
LEFT JOIN .....
WHERE
FF.Id               =   FV.FormFieldId      AND
FI.Id               =   ...
```

OUTPUT FOR NOW:

```
Count of Instances
     414400
     414400
     414400
     414400
     384800
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE:

```
Count of Instances
       5
```

If I pass to *SELECT* clause: `FI.Id` (`Id` column from `FormInstances` table) in following:

```
SELECT COUNT(FI.Id) AS [Count of Instances],
             FI.Id  AS [Instance Ids]
FROM....
```

I got correct `Instance Ids` but the same, wrong count of instances:

```
Count of Instances    Instance Ids
      414400              23
      414400              24
      414400              25
      414400              26
      384800              52
```

So why It returning incorrect count of instances?

Comment: What you are trying to count in FormInstances ? if you use a count and the primary key you will get always 1.

Comment: I want to get count of `Id` from `FormInstances` table depending on this `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Maybe is the count of the id of forminstances as a foreign key in other table?

If this is correct then move the count to the other table with this information.

Comment: Why are you repeating the join condition in the where?  You do know that putting the left in the where breaks the left?  No way the posted query returns 5 rows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are doing a join, which is multiplying the number of records.  Try using distinct within the count to remove duplicates:

```
COUNT(distinct FI.Id)
```

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas are you grouping by FI.Id somewhere accidentally? The above should do it

Comment: OMG really I missed that here are grouping. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get:

```
 Count of Instances
        5
```

You should change:

```
SELECT COUNT(FI.Id) AS [Count of Instances],
             FI.Id  AS [Instance Ids]
FROM....
```

To this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count of Instances]
FROM....
```

But I don't see how the query you posted can return the results you say you are getting so I think you've probably made a mistake in the question.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count of Instances]` return the same as `SELECT COUNT(FI.Id) AS [Count of Instances]`

Comment: Please post sample data.  I don't think it's possible for your query to return the results you say it does.

Answer (score 0):

You should select a field which has unique values and then use the Count Function with Distinct.

```
COUNT(distinct FI.Id)
```